# How to automatically center a div element that is inside another div element

Tags: css

Let's suppose the following use case:
for a working example plese look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/65/)

The HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centerElem">
         the width of this div could be variable
    </div>
</div>
```

The css style:

```
.container {
    width: 500px; /*this can also change */
}
.container .centerElem{
    margin-right: auto /*unfortunately, it works only if I set properly the width*/
    margin-left: auto /*unfortunately, it works only if I set properly the width*/
}
```

Right now it works like this:

```
        ||the width of this div could be variable|                            |
```

And I would like to make working like this, without knowing the width of inner div element:

```
        |                |the width of this div could be variable|            |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit annoying because the code in your question doesn't match the code in your jsFiddle,.

Use `display: inline-block` on `.subcon`, combined with `text-align: center` on `.container`, which you already have.

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/euYTQ/66/

Or with the code in your question: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/euYTQ/67/

Answer (score 0):

Adding `text-align:center` to the outer div seems to work just fine

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HtfZ4/

Comment: Minus for ignoring that the inner element has 2 elements inside ( side by side ). Makes all the difference.